# Framer motion complex scroll animation

Tags: animation, css-animations, motion, framer-motion

Hello everyone I'm trying to make a complex animation And I'm new to the framer motion so I need help if it's possible.
I'm trying to do this [animation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rR81OIP4EumBjU2-Q1aoe7eFgA0Sq5mS/view?usp=sharing)
all the animation will be revealed when scrolling but I don't Know How?
I tried this example but I think it will not take me any where [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-simple-animation-forked-u0lt2)

So, Any clue please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i think **useAnimationControls** will help, but i think there is another better solution or another way, but any way i wish this help you here is the [documentation](https://www.framer.com/docs/use-animation-controls/), it says that it returns a promise (and also can be used in async function with await).

like the following code:

```js
import { useAnimationControls, motion } from "framer-motion"
    
    export default function App() {
      let controls = useAnimationControls()
    
      controls
        .start({
          opacity: 1,
          backgroundColor: "red",
          color: "white",
        })
        .then(() =>
          controls.start({
            color: "black",
            backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
            x: -100,
          })
        )
        .then(() => {
          controls.start({
            opacity: 0,
            x: 100,
          })
        })
    
      return (
        <>
          <motion.div initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={controls}>
            hi there
          </motion.div>
        </>
      )
    }
```

the above code will do these things below respectively:

1. will increase the opacity to 1 and change the color & bg color
2. then it will change color & bg color again and change the x position
3. then will decrease the opacity to 0 and x position too

here is another animation library that is simple and also may be useful to use named animejs, and also they have a friend and non-boaring documentation you can check it [here](https://animejs.com/documentation/)